# Give a formula that shows that $u(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is the real part of a function of the form $f(z)=Az^2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Show that $u(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is the real part of a function of the form $f(z)=Az^2$ for some $A \in\mathbb C$. Give a formula for $A$ in terms of $a, b$ and $c$.

I first needed to prove that $u$ was harmonic if and only if $a=-c$ in order to move on to this point, and that was simple enough, but I am completely lost as to how to accomplish the second part of this question. Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should there be a $c$ multiplying $y^2$?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes! Thank you for catching that! I've made the change now :)

Comment: I think that a more rigorous statement is *"show that $u$ is the real part of $f$ if and only if $a = -c$"*.

Comment: A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka ?

Answer (score 2):

If $u = \text{Re}f$ for some holomorphic function $f$, then it and $\text{Im}f$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann identities, which (under some topological conditions) is equivalent to $u$ and $v$ being harmonic, which in turn is equivalent to $a = -c$.

Take $A = \alpha + \beta \Bbb i$ and $z = x + y \Bbb i$. Then $\text{Re} (Az^2) = \text{Re} \left( (\alpha + \beta \Bbb i) (x + y \Bbb i)^2 \right) = \alpha x^2 - 2\beta xy - \alpha y^2$. You want the last expression to be equal to $ax^2 + bxy -ay^2$ (because $c = -a$), so $\alpha = a, \ \beta = -\dfrac b 2$, therefore $f(z) = \left( a - \dfrac b 2 \Bbb i \right) z^2$.

Comment: Be careful with the ${\rm i}$. Sooner or later ISO will charge you for its use. They have "certified" it to 12 decimal places.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I get that this is meant to be a joke, but I miss it. Sorry, I know that explained jokes lose their fun, but I'm quite thick this evening.

Comment: @AlexM. I just want to make sure I'm understanding this

Why do we immediately take $A$ to be $a+bi$? Is this an assumption we have to make first before we're able to solve further?

Thank you for the fast reply by the way! :)

Comment: @Lehtia: Mind you, it's $\alpha + \beta \Bbb i$, not $a + b \Bbb i$. I take $A$ to be of this form because it is a complex number, and this is how complex numbers are written. Initially, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown real numbers, I deduce their form (with respect to $a$ and $b$) next.